# GoogleApiClient not connected in Service class Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-places-api

Hello i want to make a service class that uses Google places with GoogleApiClient, it seems that is not connecting and therefore can't get places from it.

i have the method callPlaceDetectionApi to get those places, in an activity it worked fine but in Service class don't

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {`private void callPlaceDetectionApi() throws SecurityException {
        PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
                .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
                for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.format("Place '%s' with " + "likelihood: %g", placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                            placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "nombre:" + placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                likelyPlaces.release();
            }
        });
    }
```

this is how im building the GoogleApliClient

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(LocationService.this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(LocationService.this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(LocationService.this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .build();
}
```

i tried adding .enableAutoManage(LocationService.this, GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this) because i had it when i tested it on an activity but first parameter its an FargmentActivity, since im in a service class it throws error.

on my OnLocationChanged method i tried to call "callPlaceDetectionApi()" but since its connected it doesn't do anything

```
if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
   callPlaceDetectionApi();
}
```

**EDIT**

I solved the problem i had, i was using the wrong listener import, you have to use

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
```

i was using the android LocationServices instead of Google Api LocationService.